# Does pushing a register empty that register?

Tags: x86, stack, nasm

I have read many books and instructions on this, but one thing that is never specified is what happens to a register after you push it on the stack. For example if you write in assembly "push ECX", the contents of the ECX register will be pushed on the stack (obviously). What I don't know is, once you did this, does the ECX register keep the value it contained before the push, or did it empty itself after the push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CPUs almost always *copy*, not copy + zero-the-src**.  Despite instruction mnemonics like `mov` for "move", the actual operation is "copy" (between registers), or load or store from/to memory.

A register can't be "empty", it always has some value.  (Except the legacy x87 FP stack registers; there is a separate status register that tracks which x87 registers being empty / having a value).

If an instruction destroys its source operand, that's always noted in the documentation.  Just like in high-level programming languages where reading a variable doesn't modify it unless something super weird is happening.

---

You can easily try this and find the answer yourself by using `push` with 2 different register values.  Single-step it in your debugger and notice that the register values don't change (only ESP changes, and memory).

Also you can look at (an HTML extract of) the ISA reference manual, https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push .Z E Nir quoted the "Operation" section from it.

Comment: (One reason not to use a mnemonic like `cpy` for "copy" is that `cpy` is ComPare with Y on many 8-bit micros with a register called Y, such as 6502.  So it would be confusing for people learning x86 that already knew another ISA where cp was a compare.  And also "m" is a different first letter than most other instructions.)

Answer (score 3):

The register keeps its value after `push` instruction.

`push` effects two places: the stack memory that get new value, and the value of `esp` which now points to the new top.
You can deduce that from the description of `push` operation:

```
if(StackAddressSize == 32) {
    if(OperandSize == 32) {
        ESP = ESP - 4;
        SS:ESP = Source //push doubleword
    }
    else { //OperandSize == 16
        ESP = ESP - 2;
        SS:ESP = Source; //push word
    }
}
else { //StackAddressSize == 16
    if(OperandSize == 16) {
        SP = SP - 2;
        SS:ESP = Source //push word
    }
    else { //OperandSize == 32
        SP = SP - 4;
        SS:ESP = Source; //push doubleword
    }
}
```

source: https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_269.html

https://c9x.me/x86/ is a great pocket reference for x86 instructions, use it at will!